# How to Angular material card align

Tags: angular-material

i want to align cards like below image

[image]

But my cards are aligned like this

[image]

[image]

Here is my html code

```
<md-content class="md-padding"  layout="row"  layout-wrap flex>
<div layout="column" ng-repeat="product in vm.result" flex="30">

  <md-card >
    <md-card-header>
      <md-card-header-text>
        <span class="md-title">{{ product.Product_Name }}</span>

      </md-card-header-text>
    </md-card-header>
    <img ng-src="{{ product.Image }}" class="md-card-image" alt="Image here">
    <md-card-title>
      <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Brand: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Brand }}</span>
        <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Color: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Color }}</span>
        <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Price: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Price }}</span>
        <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Url: </span><span style="margin-left:10px"><a ng-href="{{ product.Url }}">{{ product.Url }}</a></span>
        <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Category: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Category }}</span>
        <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Description: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Description }}</span>
      </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
      <md-button class="send-button md-accent md-raised" ng-click="vm.editDialog($index,product._id)">Edit</md-button>
      <md-button name="ProductId" class="send-button md-accent md-raised" ng-click="remove(product._id,'{{$index}}')">Remove</md-button>
    </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

i am trying to do this from yesterday but i am not. somebody please help me

Comment: can you show what you have in `vm.result` variable?

Comment: what you are looking for is <md-grid-list/>. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList

Comment: vm.result contains following                                    Product_Name:json.Product_Name,
Brand:json.Brand,
Color:json.Color,
Price:json.Price,
Rating:json.Rating,
Image:json.Image,
Description: json.Description,
Category: json.Category,
 URL :urla,